# How to set a value in a bitmap and retrieve a bitmap from redis using ioredis?

Tags: javascript, bitmap, redis, ioredis

I would like to use a Redis bitmap to represent values.

If I have an integer value then I want to be able to set the corresponding index of the bitmap to `1` or `true`.

I also want to be able to retrieve the entire bitmap and walk it to identify the positions of the "ones".

There is a [bitfield data structure](https://redis.io/commands/bitfield) in Redis, but I don't understand the documentation.

There are the following commands:

```
BITFIELD GET <type> <offset>
BITFIELD SET <type> <offset> <value>
```

What is the `<type>` field? What value should I use for `<value>` (string `1`?).

Finally, can anyone help me with the syntax for these commands when using [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis)?

Comment: I believe you're looking for BITOP based on our previous interchange

Comment: In any case, to get the bitmap (not BITFIELD), just GET it - it is but a string

Comment: Thank you. So it will come back as a base64 encoded sequence and then use a bit manipulation trick to find all the ones?

Comment: It'll come back as bytes, not b64, and yes - use ANDs or shifts to dismantle it

Comment: Thank you. I was intending to create bitmasks and then use `value AND mask` to find the ones, but JavaScript only supports 32-bit integers. How do I circumvent this limitation?

Comment: Munch it byte after byte

Comment: Thank you. It is little endian yes?

Comment: It should be whatever your client is using (little is the common encoding).

Comment: Thank you. To get the bit length of the string returned from redis should I use `str.length * 16` where `16` is the size of each UTF-16 JavaScript string  character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idk, but I'd go w/ 8 instinctively